# Check two elements are both in the same class

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, testing, automation

I'm trying to assert two elements are in the same class, image attached. So i want to assert the data-qa-card-id="id number" and data-qa-available-card are in the same class. But then i want to check that the data-qa-card-id="id number" and data-qa-active-card are now in the same class after the data qa-card-id-changes state? Could i just use an if statement??
[image]

The main issue i have is that I cant figure out how to check when the card id changes from available to active as there are other "card" that have available card and active card elements also so i need to zone in on the exact class of the card id

Ive tried:

```
public void assert_available_status () {

    GameId gameid = GameId.getInstance();
    String card_id = gameid.currentGameId;

    String available_card_id = game_card_id.getText();

    Assert.assertEquals(card_id, this_card_id);

    if (game_card_id.getClass() == available_card_status.getClass()) {

        System.out.println(card_id + " is an available card");
    }
```

I'm trying to assert the gameid i have matches the game id on the card then i am trying to assert they are in the same class. Not working though

Comment: *Could i just use an if statement??* - did you try it and see if it worked?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I put what ive tried in the answer

Comment: @fearghalOreilly What exactly do you want to assert as `the data-qa-card-id="id number"` and `data-qa-available-card` are in the same class? What do you mean by _data qa-card-id-changes state_?

Comment: Basically the id number is the number of a game, initially it is in data-qa-available-card section but after someone joins it moves to data-qa-active-card. Im trying to assert that the card number is changing state after someone joins.

Answer (score 1):

Game id and available card status are type of strings. you can't use == operator to compare, instead compare it using equals method as given below.

```
if (game_card_id.getClass().trim().equals(available_card_status.getClass().trim()) {

   System.out.println(card_id + " is an available card");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String firstElementClass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-qa-card-id='first id value']")).getAttribute("class");
String secondElementClass = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@data-qa-card-id='second id value']")).getAttribute("class");
Assert.assertEquals(firstElementClass, secondElementClass);
```

Hope it helps you.